# Extending Joomla Authentication Plugin

Tags: php, joomla

I want to create a Joomla authentication plugin which will execute some business logic before letting the user to authenticate, but I want to let the default authentication plugin to do that for me.

What I want to do is:

```
function onAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response) {

    // My business logic

    // Execute the onAuthenticate event of the default Joomla authentication plugin
    // which can be Joomla, OpenId etc.

}
```

So in my onAuthenticate function, I want to call the default authentication plugin's onAuthenticate function.

Any ideas? Sorry guys, I'm new to Joomla extension development.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should add your solution in as an answer then select it as the best answer in case someone else has the same or a similar question.

Comment: Rather than post the answer as an edit to the question, please post it as an answer below. You can then accept it in 2 days. Currently, it will show up as unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to stackoverflow. Now I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by just keeping my plugin and the joomla authentication plugin activated together and I set 0 in the Order column for my plugin so it will get notified of onAuthenticate before Joomla's auth plugin.